# How to phrase a question with many answers properly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

The question goes as follows:

Find all values of $n$ such that $(1+i)^n + (1-i)^n = 0$

In my final line of work, I got $i^n = -1$

So how do I properly phrase the answer? There are multiple values.

Something like this: $n =2,6,10, 14,18... \infty $? and $n = -2,-6...-\infty$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it in set-builder notation. $\{4k+2 : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$